# Adding bashrc file to bash_profile

Tags: bash

I am trying to run `bashrc` file from `bash_profile`:

```
if [-f ~/.bashrc]; then 
   source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

What is `-f` above please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [GNU Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html):

```
-f file

    True if file exists and is a regular file.
```

So it is checking if the `.bashrc` file exists in your user home directory.

Answer (score 2):

It just tests if the file exists and is a regular file (not a directory or pipe or socket or something). See `help test`.